# Delay an image transition in ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, overlay

How can I delay image left to right transition in ffmpeg?

`[1:v]format=rgba,fade=in:st=30:d=0.3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=40:d=0.3:alpha=1[png];[vid][png]overlay=x='min(-(30-0.3)*w+2*w*t/3,15)':y=3*(H-h)/4-0.0:shortest=1`

Because I start fade in at 30 sec, I set initial position of x to 27.7 and speed to `2*w*t/3`. But the image does not appear at 30 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the image should be at x=15 when the fade-in finishes. So, at 30.3 s, it's at x=15, and it's traveling at w*2/3 /second. So, in 30+0.3 seconds, it will have traveled `30.3*w*(2/3)`, so starting point is `15 - (30+0.3)*w*2/3`
Add the movement to that.

`x='min(15-(30+0.3)*w*2/3+w*t*2/3,15)'`